# Azure Service Bus MessageLockLostException is firiing inadvertently

Tags: azure, exception, azureservicebus

MessageLockLostException is occurring for no reason. We set our lock time to 1 minute and intermittently this exception is thrown after 20 seconds into the processing. This happens for no reason.  We have noticed that it generally happens at the end or beginning of a minute. What I mean is:

-> Message arrives on service bus topic at 8:30:42

-> Function picks up message at 8:30:42 apparently begins processing

-> The response time on the process is 19.4 seconds

-> remember my lock is 1 minute

What my function processing does

```
-> at 8:30:44 I made a call out to serivceX (http) (2 seconds later)
-> this responded in 341 milliseconds
-> at 8:31:02 the MessageLockLostException is being thrown
```

Hmmm… maybe because the function is still processing over the minute and somehow because there is a change from 8:31:59 .. 8:32:00 .. 8:32:01??? Follow me here…

-> After the exception, the message lock is released and it is processed by another function instance at 8:31:02 and completes in 743 milliseconds

Again, the same thing occurs

-> Message arrives on service bus topic at 8:30:37

-> Function picks up message at 8:30:39 apparently begins processing (2 seconds later)

-> The response time on the process is 19.5 seconds

-> remember my lock is 1 minute

What my function processing does

```
-> at 8:30:55 I made a call out to serivceX (http)
-> this responded in 1.4 seconds
-> at 8:30:58 the MessageLockLostException is being thrown
```

Hmmm… maybe because the function is still processing and the end of the minute is approaching 8:30:59 ??? Follow me here…

-> After the exception, the message lock is released and it is processed by another function instance at 8:31:38 and completes in 1.8 seconds

Again, the same thing occurs

-> Message arrives on service bus topic at 10:43:01

-> Function picks up message at 10:43:02 apparently begins processing (1 second later)

-> The response time on the process is 19.3 seconds

-> remember my lock is 1 minute

What my function processing does

```
-> at 10:43:02 I made a call out to serivceX (http)
-> this responded in 341 milliseconds
-> at 10:43:21 the MessageLockLostException is being thrown
```

Hmmm… maybe because the function started processing and the beginning of the minute 10:43:02 ??? Follow me here…

-> After the exception, the message lock is released and it is processed by another function instance at 10:44:02 and completes in 2.0 seconds

Again, the same thing occurs

-> Message arrives on service bus topic at 2:24:31

-> Function picks up message at 2:24:35 apparently begins processing (4 seconds later)

-> The response time on the process is 19.3 seconds

-> remember my lock is 1 minute

What my function processing does

```
-> at 2:24:35 I made a call out to serivceX (http)
-> this responded in 444 milliseconds
-> at 2:24:54 the MessageLockLostException is being thrown
```

Hmmm… maybe because the function is still processing towards the end of the minute is approaching 2:24:54 .. 2:24:55, etc ??? Follow me here…

-> After the exception, the message lock is released and it is processed by another function instance at 2:25:35 and completes in 1.9 seconds

Again, the same thing occurs

-> Message arrives on service bus topic at 2:30:55

-> Function picks up message at 2:30:56 apparently begins processing (1 second later)

-> The response time on the process is 19.2 seconds

-> remember my lock is 1 minute

What my function processing does

```
-> at 2:30:56 I made a call out to serivceX (http)
-> this responded in 468 milliseconds
-> at 2:31:15 the MessageLockLostException is being thrown
```

Hmmm… no ration on this on but, please, still Follow me here…

-> After the exception, the message lock is released and it is processed by another function instance at 2:31:56 and completes in 1.6 seconds

Again, the same thing occurs

-> Message arrives on service bus topic at 11:52:55

-> Function picks up message at 11:52:56 apparently begins processing (1 second later)

-> The response time on the process is 19.3 seconds

-> remember my lock is 1 minute

What my function processing does

```
-> at 11:52:56 I made a call out to serivceX (http)
-> this responded in 509 milliseconds
-> at 11:53:15 the MessageLockLostException is being thrown
```

Hmmm… no ration on this on but, please, still Follow me here…

-> After the exception, the message lock is released and it is processed by another function instance at 11:53:55 and completes in 1.8 seconds

Notice sporadic failures all about 19.2-19.4 seconds… but no consistency in the failures…

And after the MessageLockLostException throws, the next function is successful

Comment: What's the prefetch? Is MaxLockDuration modified by something else? Ha e you tried to re-create the queue?